# How to compare two ArrayList and get list1 with filter using java streams

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists list1 & list2 of type List

```
Term{
long sId;
int rowNum;
long psid;
String name;
}

List<Term> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Term> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to return all the items from list1 where (list1.psid != list2.psid).

I tried this but its not working

```
public List<Term> getFilteredRowNum(List<Term> list1, List<Term> list2) {
        List<Long> psid = list2.stream().map(x -> x.getPsid()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return list1.stream().filter(x -> !psid.contains(x.getPsid())).map(x -> x.getRowNum()+1).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

I want to get all the records in list1 which satisfies fallowing condition
if(list1.psid != list2.psid)

```
Sample Date:
List1: rowNum     psId    name    sid
       1         1288     home    101
       1         9012     home    101
       2         1296     office  150
       3         1290     park    161

List2: rowNum     psId    name    sid
       1          9012    home    101
       2         1296     office  150
       3         1290     park    161

List1 psId not in list2 so I am expecting fallowing list as result from list1

Expected: List1
 rowNum     psId    name    sid
 1         1288     home    101
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for an inner `anyMatch` in the filter predicate as:

```
public List<Term> getFilteredRowNum(List<Term> termList1, List<Term> termList2) {
    return termList1.stream()
            .filter(term1 -> termList2.stream()
                    .anyMatch(term2 -> term1.getSId() == term2.getSId()
                            && term1.getPsid() != term2.getPsid()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Another way to solve that would be to create a `Map` of `sid` to a `Set` of `psid`s present in any of the list using `groupingBy` and `mapping`

```
Map<Long, Set<Long>> sIdToPsIdsMap = termList2.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Term::getSId, 
                Collectors.mapping(Term::getPsid, Collectors.toSet())));
```

and further using it for `filter` conditions as

```
return termList1.stream()
        .filter(term1 -> sIdToPsIdsMap.containsKey(term1.getSId())
                && !sIdToPsIdsMap.get(term1.getSId()).contains(term1.getPsid()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I just wanted to add your second solution as it improves the performance for lange lists. You also can use a single condition using `Map.getOrDefault()`: `!sIdToPsIdsMap.getOrDefault(term1.getSId(), new HashSet<>()).contains(term1.getPsid())`.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp but wouldn't that always perform a `contains` check despite the absence of the `key`?

Comment: I tried this as per your solution but its not filtering. I even tried looking only for one condition i.e., list1 psId (not in) list2 psId.                                                                            
 public List<Term> getFilteredSBDRowNum(List<Term> list1, List<Term> list2) {

  return list1.stream().filter(term1 -> list2.stream().anyMatch(term2 -> term1.getPsid() != term2.getPsid())).collect(Collectors.toList());

 }

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp , Naman this is for larger list and I should consider performance as one of the key factor.

Comment: @Sruthi Could you update the question with sample input, expected output and current output that you're getting? Would clarify further what is it that we are missing.

Comment: @Sruthi and what result do you get from the 2nd solution here in the solution?

Comment: @Naman I didnot tried second solution. first solution I am getting all the list1 as it is. will try Map<Long, Set<Long>>  solution

Comment: @Sruthi Even with the first solution, I can confirm that the `List` returned after using the sample input would include only one element in the output which is same as the expected output.

Comment: @Naman its not working giving me syntax error. Also I want to group by rowNum.

Comment: @Naman okay i will debug and see now sure where its getting wrong.

Comment: @Sruthi Well the question or the samples didn't really mention about the `groupingBy` with `rowNum`. Do update the question with complete details while posting it. Never the less, if this solution works, try `groupingBy` rowNum by yourself and post a separate question if that gets you stuck somewhere. (Just be sure of filling in with complete details while you post a question.)

Comment: @Naman okay sure will post diff questions. thanks for helping.